# How to Show Popup Menu near to Listview each item on Item Click Event?

Tags: android, listview

How to Show Popup Menu near to Listview  each item on Item Click Event ?

This is my code. I want to show Popup menu near to listview item on item click. but it shows at bottom only. So help me to show popup menu near to list item which was clicked. Thank you .

```
   package saro.example.com.task2_listview;

    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.view.ContextMenu;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.PopupWindow;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.PopupMenu;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView list;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry",
                    "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X","Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry"};

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    int pos = parent.getPositionForView(v);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pos+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, list);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    //         
                    popup.show();

                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this just pass of your adapter view `v` insted of `list` as view in your pop up menu like below code

**use this** `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);`

**insted of** `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, list);`

**code**

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    int pos = parent.getPositionForView(v);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pos+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    //         
                    popup.show();

                }

            });
```

Comment: most welcome @Saravana you can accept one of ans so it can help other also

Answer (score 2):

From [PopupMenu (Context context, View anchor)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#PopupMenu(android.content.Context,%20android.view.View))

> anchor    View: Anchor view for this popup. `The popup will appear below
>   the anchor` if there is room, or above it if there is not.

Instead of passing the list reference use `v`

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
```

because `v` here is the view

> The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view
>   provided by the adapter)

Comment: Thanks Bro . It Works.

Comment: just for the info, i you look at the time frame by hovering over , i posted this answer first rest is your choice for accepting most helpful answer , happy coding